# Github Actions Last Build API

Tags: jenkins, github, api

I'm looking for an option similar to Jenkins where I can view the last build, last successful build, last failed build, etc. with a simple api call. The Jenkins example would be:

```
jenkins_url + /job/${job_name}/lastBuild/
```

Does Github Actions offer anything comparable to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List workflow runs](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/workflow-runs/#list-workflow-runs) would be the equivalent API endpoint in Github Actions:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/actions/workflows/:workflow_id/runs
```

You can use the `status` query parameter e.g. to filter for successful runs:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/actions/workflows/:workflow_id/runs?status=success
```